# MATLAB addpath(genpath()) command not working if run under MSYS2

Tags: python, matlab, msys2, msys

I am running into a very odd issue.

1: What works:

- Start MATLAB with Windows Command Prompt, use the command `addpath(genpath('C:\Users\myName\Desktop\myProjectLocation'))`
- Start MATLAB with Windows Command Prompt, use the folder explorer to find the project and add all folders/subfolders.
- Start MATLAB with the Windows Command Prompt using `matlab -wait -nodisplay -nodesktop -r "addpath(genpath('C:\Users\myName\Desktop\myProjectLocation')); myMatlabScript"`
- Start MATLAB with MSYS2, use the folder explorer to find the project and add all folders/subfolders. (So far, this has always worked)

2: What *sometimes* doesn't work:

- Start MATLAB with MSYS2, use the command `addpath(genpath('C:\Users\myName\Desktop\myProjectLocation'))`
- Start MATLAB with MSYS2 using `matlab -wait -nodisplay -nodesktop -r "addpath(genpath('C:\Users\myName\Desktop\myProjectLocation')); myMatlabScript"`

If I try any of the second ones, it *sometimes* silently fails to load some DLLs (I think) and the results it outputs are garbage.

I am not sure why. If I take one of the dlls and run `which` on them, the path is indeed different. However, it resolves to the same location through a soft link.

If I could have my Python script appropriately use a Windows terminal instead of a MSYS2 terminal, that might fix it. However, the Python script is run through MSYS2, and I cannot easily install Python on Windows natively.

**Setup:**

- Windows 10, latest updates
- MATLAB R2016B, without Update 7 (No, I cannot update MATLAB, it's a requirement)
- MSYS2 is installed and all packages are updated

**EDIT:**

Just installed Python on Windows itself and ran it from the command prompt. Still didn't work. I give up, I have no idea why this is failing. Maybe some MATLABR2016 bug. :(

Comment: Have you tried `/c/Users/myName/Desktop/myProjectLocation`?